# Core Data segue issue with saving changes

Tags: ios, core-data, segue

I had my project working, and decided I will introduce a settings page for users to make basic adjustments.

```
Entity name: "Setting"
Attribute: "settingTimeOverrideSlider"
-> I created the NSManagedObject Subclass
```

I added (and embedded) the SettingsViewController, the segue, named the segue.

On that page I'm using a button to save changes. This button called a method in my CoreViewController via `[super saveAndDismiss]` and I know it gets in there (checked with NSLog).

Here's the method:

```
-(void)saveAndDismiss
{
    NSLog(@"In Save And Dismiss");
    NSError *error = nil;
    if ([self.managedObjectContext hasChanges]) {
        NSLog(@"In Save And Dismiss - has changes");
        if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {                 // save failed
            NSLog(@"Save failed: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        } else {                                                        // save succeeded
            NSLog(@"Save Succeeded");
        }
    }
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];    
}
```

But for some reason, it never gets into the first `if()`, where I have my next debug NSLog.

I believe my problem is my `prepareForSegue` in my main page, as all the other segues are going to tableViews. I'm not sure if I have my segue setup right

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(UITableViewCell*)sender
{
    // segues 1-3
    if ([[segue identifier]isEqualToString:@"segue4"])
    {
        // some other Segue
    }

    if ([[segue identifier]isEqualToString:@"toSettings"])
    {
        UINavigationController *settingsViewController = segue.destinationViewController;

        SettingsViewController *editSettingsViewController = (SettingsViewController*)settingsViewController.topViewController;

        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:0];

        Setting *editSettings = (Setting*)[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

        editSettingsViewController.editSetting = editSettings;
    }
}
```

In my SettingsViewController.h, I subclass my SettingsViewController to be part of my CoreViewController as so:

```
// SettingsViewController.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Setting.h"
#import "CoreViewController.h"

@interface SettingsViewController : CoreViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong)Setting editSetting;

@property (nonatomic, strong)Setting *editSetting;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *editSaveButton;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *timeOverrideTextlabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *timeFormatSelector;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISwitch *timeOverrideSlider;

- (IBAction)cancel:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender;
- (IBAction)editSave:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender;
- (IBAction)timeOverride:(UISwitch *)sender;
```

Now as I'm trying to retrieve information from persistent memory, do I need to change the above statement to

```
@interface SettingsViewController : CoreViewController
    <NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate>
```

?

```
//SettingsViewController.m
#import "SettingsViewController.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface SettingsViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong)NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (nonatomic, strong)NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;
```

Can't seem to wrap my head around what's wrong here, but I'm sure it is in my `prepareForSegue` method (listed above).

Like I said, all the other segue if-statement where used to link to TableViews and work fine.

I'm trying to set my Attribute like this

```
editSetting.settingTimeOverrideSlider = @YES;
```

and then I call

```
[super saveAndDismiss];


- (IBAction)editSave:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender
{
    if ([_editSaveButton.title isEqualToString:@"Edit"])
    {
        [self setTitle:@"Edit Settings"];

        _timeFormatSelector.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        _timeOverrideSlider.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

        _editSaveButton.title = @"Save";
    } else if ([_editSaveButton.title isEqualToString:@"Save"])
    {
        [self setTitle:@"Settings"];

        NSLog(@"SAVING-SVC");
        editSetting.settingTimeOverrideSlider = @YES; // THIS IS WHAT SHOULD CHANGE IN CORE DATA
        [super saveAndDismiss];
    }
}
```

Comment: As a check, could you please confirm that you do not mean to code in your `prepareForSegue` method instead `if (![[segue identifier]isEqualToString:@"segue4"])`?

Comment: Regarding your method `saveAndDismiss`, that your code does not enter the first `if` statement indicates that your managedObjectContext has not changed. What properties / attributes / etc. are you expecting to change / have changed?

Comment: I disguised all the other segue if's,
I have a switch in my view, and a boolvalue in core data,
I'm using the boolvalue to remember the status of the switch, even when app closes. or do I not need to do that? are buttons persistent?

I added my editSave method in the code above and the properties / attributes I changed are included as well
it is
    editSetting.settingTimeOverrideSlider = @YES;

Comment: Are you passing the MOC to the setting view controller? is it by any chance `nil`?

Comment: That would be in my segue if-statemnt, correct?
something along the lines:
Setting *someName = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Setting" inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];
but I'm not sure how to combine that in the whole segue code, see above in original post, if you could explain what I'm doing wrong in there, and how I could implement that?

Comment: @Studiologe you might want to add `editSettingsViewController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext` to your segue code, or something equivalent to getting the source view controller MOC and passing it to the destination view controller

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't send in the `fetchedResultsController` nor the `managedObjectContext` to the SettingsViewController. You should limit the amount of information that needs to be configured where possible. You are already sending in the `editSetting`, which is enough information to achieve the results you want.

In `SettingsViewController`, delete the following two lines:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong)NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (nonatomic, strong)NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;
```

Instead, you should access the managed object context from the [NSManagedObject](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObject_Class/Reference/NSManagedObject.html) directly.

Your `saveAndDismiss` should now look like this:

```
-(void)saveAndDismiss
{
    NSLog(@"In Save And Dismiss");
    NSError *error = nil;
    if ([self.editSetting.managedObjectContext hasChanges]) {
        NSLog(@"In Save And Dismiss - has changes");
        if (![self.editSetting.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {                 // save failed
            NSLog(@"Save failed: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        } else {                                                        // save succeeded
            NSLog(@"Save Succeeded");
        }
    }
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];    
}
```

Notice how `self.managedObjectContext` became `self.editSetting.managedObjectContext`.

Better yet, you can probably change `[self.editSetting.managedObjectContext hasChanges]` to `[self.editSetting isUpdated]`.

Comment: How to access mod from NSManagedObject directly?

My 
-(void)saveAndDismiss
I can't modify, it would mess up my othertableview screens, that use it too, it's located in CoreViewController.m
I have no access to editSetting from CoreViewController.m

I tried to #Import my SettingsViewController in there, but still I'm getting an error on this line:
if ([Setting.editSetting isUpdated]) {
//ERROR is: Property 'editSetting' not found on object of type 'Setting'
even though I have it in my SettingsViewController.h with
property (nonatomic, strong)Setting *editSetting;
under @Interface declared....

Comment: I made all the changes, as you suggested and I tried both with [self.editSetting.managedObjectContext hasChanges] and with [ self.editSetting isUpdated], but I never get to see the NSLog(@"In Save And Dismiss - has changes"); Message, it never goes into that IF. Why is that? and how can I make sure that the context changes?

Comment: Is maybe my -(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(UITableViewCell*)sender
the problem, as it reads sender:(UITableViewCell)??
And I'm entering the settings page via a button, and not from selecting a cell?
I added an NSLog output for debugging in key if statement for the "toSettings" Segue and it actually showed me, when I select the settings page, that it goes into the right IF..